# How to encrypt a string to a string of the same size is Python

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I have strings about 500 chars long and I'd like to encrypt them so that resulting string has the same length (or just slightly different). I need two way enryption and decryption using another "secret" string known to both sides. It doesn't need to be very secure, I prefer faster solutions.

Comment: Sounds like AES is a perfect fit.

Comment: How do I get AES to return the same length string?

Comment: rot13 is very fast and preserves length! `data = "plaintext".encode("rot13")`.

Answer (score 2):

From the post here: [Encrypt string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810223/encrypt-string-in-python)

using http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/

```
crypter = Crypter.Read("/path/to/your/keys")
ciphertext = crypter.Encrypt("Secret message")
```

Comment: I don't want to use keys, I want to use another string as a secret. Also seems like keyczar is no longer installable from pypi, not a good sign.

Comment: copied from the dupe answer.

Comment: In future, please flag instead. The whole point of marking questions as duplicates is so we don't have to needlessly copy answers across questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the length, then you want to use a [stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher)

Note that both parties need to know key (secret) and [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) (not secret, but must be unique).

It is not safe to reuse same key without a different IV, thus you'd need to communicate new IV across somehow, which effectively lengthens your encrypted package.

Furthermore, you really need to consider replay attacks -- what happens if someone intercepts your message and then sends it again and again.

Here's simple example for RC4, using `pycrypto`, no IV (RC4 doesn't support it):

```
import Crypto.Cipher.ARC4
plaintext = "x" * 13
c1 = Crypto.Cipher.ARC4.new(key="1")
ciphertext = c.encrypt(plaintext)
assert len(ciphertext) == len(plaintext)
c2 = Crypto.Cipher.ARC4.new(key="1")
result = c2.descrypt(ciphertext)
assert result == plaintext
```